# Systemd Networkd MAC Address generation for VLAN Interfaces

Tags: systemd

I'm creating a VLAN interface with networkd like this on a bunch of servers with equal config:

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan3
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=3
```

Then I'm creating an interface like this with it:

```
[Match]
Name=vlan3

[Network]
Address=10.1.0.x/24
```

Where `x` is a unique number for every server.

My problem is that the VLAN is not really usable as networkd seems to choose the same MAC address (in my case `72:ae:43:d7:0f:d7`) on every server.
I know I can set a MAC address using `MACAddress` or influence the generation via `MACAddressPolicy`. But what is networkd without specifying either?

Comment: Are you asking what the default behavior is if you don't specify `MACAddress` or `MACAddressPolicy` ?

Comment: Yes but as far as I see the default of `MACAddressPolicy` is neither of both options. `MACAddress` cannot have a sensible default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default MACAddress for a `[NetDev]` section is defined in the [official documentation](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html#):

> The MAC address to use for the device. If none is given, one is generated based on the interface name and the [machine-id(5)](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html#).

If all your machines have the same MAC Address being generated, it's because they have the same `machine-id`. Refer to the linked official docs on `machine-id` on how you can influence that.